# sql joins The multi-part identifier could not be found

Tags: t-sql, join

here`s my query

```
SELECT cont.FILTER_VALUE as filter,
    o.[OBJECT_ID] as Id, o.[OBJECT_NAME] as Name, o.DESCRIPTION as Description, o.CREATED as Created,
     o.MODIFIED as Modified,  u.[LOGIN] as LastModifiedByLogin, o.[OBJECT_NAME] as ObjectName, t.[TEMPLATE_NAME] as TemplateName--,p.[PAGE_NAME] as PageName 
    FROM 
     [OBJECT] AS o
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [CONTAINER] as cont 
     on cont.[OBJECT_ID] = o.[OBJECT_ID]

     LEFT JOIN [OBJECT_VALUES] AS ov ON
     ov.[OBJECT_ID] = o.[OBJECT_ID]
     LEFT JOIN [PAGE] AS p ON o.[PAGE_ID] = p.[PAGE_ID] 
     INNER JOIN [USERS] as u on u.[USER_ID] = o.LAST_MODIFIED_BY INNER JOIN [PAGE_TEMPLATE] as t 
     on o.[PAGE_TEMPLATE_ID] = t.[PAGE_TEMPLATE_ID] INNER JOIN [site] as s on t.SITE_ID = s.SITE_ID 
     WHERE
     s.SITE_ID = '34' --AND сont.[FILTER_VALUE] is null--like '%fff%'
```

And it works nice, until I remove the comment.

Here's a mess of joins, still it has sense. I `inner join` main table with couple of others, and `left join` with optional, so, that I have a column, that contains `cont.FILTER_VALUE as filter`, its null in some records, I can get it, but I cant filter by this field.

I get `The multi-part identifier "сont.FILTER_VALUE" could not be bound.`

I've looked through similar topics, but found no useful information. I don't use any old SQL dialects: everywhere I use `INNER/LEFT` joins, tried `group by` and `order by`, tried to re-order joins - nothing helped. I guess I just don't understand something important about joins, could you tell me, please.

Thanx.

Comment: Is FILTER_VALUE a field in the CONTAINER table?

Comment: sure it is, i`ve spent a lot of time with this query, Ive already checked this fact=)

Comment: Why are you returning a value in your select list you know to be null?

Comment: I notice you do not use schema names, so perhaps there is more than one CONTAINER table. try SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE Name = 'CONTAINER'

Comment: Just for the future, I always put all inner joins before any left joins. I find it makes the query easier to understand.

Comment: What is really wierd is that it doesn't object to cont.FILTER_VALUE in the select when you have the where part commented out. The only differnce I see is that the first one doesn't have [] around it which should not make a differnce. But hey, try it without the brackets.

Comment: notice you do not use schema names, so perhaps there is more than one CONTAINER table. try SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE Name = 'CONTAINER' I`ve got obly one container, unfortunatelly

Comment: CAn you show some sample data returned when you run it without the where clause on Filter_value?

Comment: When I execute query withount commented part, I get a usual set of data, with nuls in filter field in some rows

Comment: Just for the future, I always put all inner joins before any left joins. I find it makes the query easier to understand -Ive tried re-ordering joins, it doesnt help, but i agree, that you way it looks better

Answer (score 0):

if you wrote it like this:
`s.SITE_ID = '34' AND сont.[FILTER_VALUE] is null like '%fff%'`
its just wrong syntax. you're missing a column for the LIKE function (in which column does the query suppose to look for the pattern?). if you didnt write it like that, please post what you did write

Comment: I assumed 2 different comments.

Comment: as you see, there is another comment after is null, it is not hte problem, i get an error every time I try to filter by field cont.[FILTER_VALUE] or any other fields of cont table, which is LEFT JOINED, so it can have null values, maybe this is the problem, isn`t it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're getting your error, but try this just in case, while we wait for a better answer:

```
SELECT FILTER_VALUE as filter
   , o.[OBJECT_ID] as Id
   , o.[OBJECT_NAME] as Name
   , o.DESCRIPTION as Description
   , o.CREATED as Created
   , o.MODIFIED as Modified
   , u.[LOGIN] as LastModifiedByLogin
   , o.[OBJECT_NAME] as ObjectName
   , t.[TEMPLATE_NAME] as TemplateName
FROM [OBJECT] AS o
INNER JOIN [USERS] as u 
  ON u.[USER_ID] = o.LAST_MODIFIED_BY 
INNER JOIN [PAGE_TEMPLATE] as t 
  ON o.[PAGE_TEMPLATE_ID] = t.[PAGE_TEMPLATE_ID] 
INNER JOIN [site] as s 
  ON t.SITE_ID = s.SITE_ID 
LEFT JOIN [CONTAINER] as cont 
  ON cont.[OBJECT_ID] = o.[OBJECT_ID]
LEFT JOIN [OBJECT_VALUES] AS ov 
  ON ov.[OBJECT_ID] = o.[OBJECT_ID]
LEFT JOIN [PAGE] AS p 
  ON o.[PAGE_ID] = p.[PAGE_ID] 
WHERE s.SITE_ID = '34' AND FILTER_VALUE IS NULL
```

Comment: I`ve already tryed such query, as I said, i get the error every time i try to filter the set using any column of container table

Comment: and exactly your query executed with same result

Comment: Missed that comment.  How about not using the alias for filter_value, same result?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this problem, using CTE, still I wonder, why did I have problems without cte.

This way it works good

```
with query_CTE
AS
(
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.[OBJECT_ID] asc) as rowNum,
o.[OBJECT_ID] as Id, o.[OBJECT_NAME] as Name, o.DESCRIPTION as Description, o.CREATED as Created,
 o.MODIFIED as Modified,  u.[LOGIN] as LastModifiedByLogin, o.[OBJECT_NAME] as ObjectName, t.[TEMPLATE_NAME] as TemplateName,p.[PAGE_NAME] as PageName,

 s.SITE_ID, t.PAGE_TEMPLATE_ID, p.PAGE_ID, ov.VARIABLE_NAME, ov.VARIABLE_VALUE, cont.FILTER_VALUE, cont.DYNAMIC_CONTENT_VARIABLE, cont.SELECT_START,
 cont.SELECT_TOTAL  
FROM [OBJECT] AS o
INNER JOIN [USERS] as u 
  ON u.[USER_ID] = o.LAST_MODIFIED_BY 
INNER JOIN [PAGE_TEMPLATE] as t 
  ON o.[PAGE_TEMPLATE_ID] = t.[PAGE_TEMPLATE_ID] 
INNER JOIN [site] as s 
  ON t.SITE_ID = s.SITE_ID 
LEFT JOIN [CONTAINER] as cont 
  ON cont.[OBJECT_ID] = o.[OBJECT_ID]
LEFT JOIN [OBJECT_VALUES] AS ov 
  ON ov.[OBJECT_ID] = o.[OBJECT_ID]
LEFT JOIN [PAGE] AS p 
  ON o.[PAGE_ID] = p.[PAGE_ID]
```

)

select rowNum,
Id, Name,[Description], Created, Modified, LastModifiedByLogin, ObjectName, TemplateName,PageName
from query_CTE